# SonarQube is not getting up on AWS EKS Fargate with EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, sonarqube, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I'm trying to run the SonarQube on AWS EKS using Fargate technology. I'm using the AWS EFS file system as Fargate supports only EFS CSI driver (and not EBS).

I'm getting an error:-

```
vinod827@Vinods-MacBook-Pro efs % kubectl logs sonarqube-57c9d765d8-sjc4k -f
2021.03.05 08:19:32 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2021.03.05 08:19:32 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:45113]
2021.03.05 08:19:32 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2021.03.05 08:19:32 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
warning: no-jdk distributions that do not bundle a JDK are deprecated and will be removed in a future release
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2021.03.05 08:19:35 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] version[7.10.2], pid[39], build[oss/tar/747e1cc71def077253878a59143c1f785afa92b9/2021-01-13T00:42:12.435326Z], OS[Linux/4.14.209-160.339.amzn2.x86_64/amd64], JVM[AdoptOpenJDK/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/11.0.10/11.0.10+9]
2021.03.05 08:19:35 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM home [/opt/java/openjdk]
2021.03.05 08:19:35 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM arguments [-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp, -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -Des.enforce.bootstrap.checks=true, -Xmx512m, -Xms512m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Des.path.home=/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/opt/sonarqube/temp/conf/es, -Des.distribution.flavor=oss, -Des.distribution.type=tar, -Des.bundled_jdk=false]
2021.03.05 08:19:35 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [analysis-common]
2021.03.05 08:19:35 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [lang-painless]
2021.03.05 08:19:35 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join]
2021.03.05 08:19:35 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [percolator]
2021.03.05 08:19:35 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4]
2021.03.05 08:19:35 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no plugins loaded
2021.03.05 08:19:35 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/opt/sonarqube/data (127.0.0.1:/)]], net usable_space [8191.9pb], net total_space [8191.9pb], types [nfs4]
2021.03.05 08:19:35 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] heap size [494.9mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2021.03.05 08:19:36 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] node name [sonarqube], node ID [lCWfo3LiTKii0jH6_B5RIw], cluster name [sonarqube], roles [master, remote_cluster_client, data, ingest]
2021.03.05 08:19:39 INFO  es[][o.e.t.NettyAllocator] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=unpooled, suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb, factors={es.unsafe.use_unpooled_allocator=null, g1gc_enabled=false, g1gc_region_size=0b, heap_size=494.9mb}]
2021.03.05 08:19:40 INFO  es[][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule] using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]
2021.03.05 08:19:40 WARN  es[][o.e.g.DanglingIndicesState] gateway.auto_import_dangling_indices is disabled, dangling indices will not be automatically detected or imported and must be managed manually
2021.03.05 08:19:40 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initialized
2021.03.05 08:19:40 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] starting ...
2021.03.05 08:19:40 INFO  es[][o.e.t.TransportService] publish_address {127.0.0.1:45113}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:45113}
2021.03.05 08:19:41 INFO  es[][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks] explicitly enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max number of threads [1024] for user [sonarqube] is too low, increase to at least [4096]
[2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at /opt/sonarqube/logs/sonarqube.log
2021.03.05 08:19:41 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopping ...
2021.03.05 08:19:41 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopped
2021.03.05 08:19:41 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closing ...
2021.03.05 08:19:41 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closed
2021.03.05 08:19:41 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 78
2021.03.05 08:19:41 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2021.03.05 08:19:41 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

The error clearly says:-

```
ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max number of threads [1024] for user [sonarqube] is too low, increase to at least [4096]
[2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at /opt/sonarqube/logs/sonarqube.log
```

My SonarQube deployment manifest:-

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: sonarqube
  name: sonarqube
  namespace: cicd
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sonarqube
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sonarqube
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sonarqube
          image: sonarqube:latest
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 4
              memory: "8Gi"
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/opt/sonarqube/data/"
            name: sonar-data
          - mountPath: "/opt/sonarqube/extensions/"
            name: sonar-extensions
          env:
          - name: "SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME"
            valueFrom:
             configMapKeyRef:
               name: configuration
               key: USERNAME
          - name: "SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL"
            valueFrom:
             configMapKeyRef:
               name: configuration
               key: URL
          - name: "SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD"
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: db-password
                key: password
          ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
            protocol: TCP


      volumes:
      - name: sonar-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: claim-sonar-data

      - name: sonar-extensions
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: claim-sonar-extensions
```

EFS CSI:-

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-sonar-data
  namespace: cicd
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-cd4c48b5

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: claim-sonar-data
  namespace: cicd
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-sonar-extensions
  namespace: cicd
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-dc4c48a4

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: claim-sonar-extensions
  namespace: cicd
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
```

I literally do not know what this error means. To be honest, I tried my best to figure out the issue and stuck over the last couple of days.

There is no problem with EKS cluster or EFS mounting:-

1. Tried to create a normal NGINX pod using the same file (replacing just the image name). The pods started running successfully on the same cluster and I was able to see the EFS volumes mounted on it.